# XGBoost plot_importance doesn't show feature names

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm using XGBoost with Python and have successfully trained a model using the XGBoost `train()` function called on `DMatrix` data. The matrix was created from a Pandas dataframe, which has feature names for the columns.

```
Xtrain, Xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(df[feature_names], y, \
                                    test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(Xtrain, label=ytrain)

model = xgb.train(xgb_params, dtrain, num_boost_round=60, \
                  early_stopping_rounds=50, maximize=False, verbose_eval=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=5, ax=ax)
```

I want to now see the feature importance using the `xgboost.plot_importance()` function, but the resulting plot doesn't show the feature names. Instead, the features are listed as `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, etc. as shown below.

[image]

I think the problem is that I converted my original Pandas data frame into a DMatrix. How can I associate feature names properly so that the feature importance plot shows them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to use the `feature_names` parameter when creating your `xgb.DMatrix`

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(Xtrain, label=ytrain, feature_names=feature_names)
```

Comment: I did this, and I'm still getting `f##` as the names of the features in the feature importance

Answer (score 56):

If you're using the scikit-learn wrapper you'll need to access the underlying XGBoost Booster and set the feature names on it, instead of the scikit model, like so:

```
model = joblib.load("your_saved.model")
model.get_booster().feature_names = ["your", "feature", "name", "list"]
xgboost.plot_importance(model.get_booster())
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: But how do you know what is the correct order of features to use? How can you make sure the true feature names are mapped correctly to the `f##` feature names?

Answer (score 7):

`train_test_split` will convert the dataframe to numpy array which dont have columns information anymore.

Either you can do what @piRSquared suggested and pass the features as a parameter to DMatrix constructor. Or else, you can convert the numpy array returned from the `train_test_split` to a Dataframe and then use your code.

```
Xtrain, Xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(df[feature_names], y, \
                                    test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# See below two lines
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=Xtrain, columns=feature_names)
Xval = pd.DataFrame(data=Xval, columns=feature_names)

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(Xtrain, label=ytrain)
```

Answer (score 6):

With Scikit-Learn Wrapper interface "XGBClassifier",plot_importance reuturns class "matplotlib Axes". So we can employ axes.set_yticklabels.

`plot_importance(model).set_yticklabels(['feature1','feature2'])`

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way I found whiles playing around with `feature_names`. While playing around with it, I wrote this which works on XGBoost v0.80 which I'm currently running.

```
## Saving the model to disk
model.save_model('foo.model')
with open('foo_fnames.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(model.feature_names))

## Later, when you want to retrieve the model...
model2 = xgb.Booster({"nthread": nThreads})
model2.load_model("foo.model")

with open("foo_fnames.txt", "r") as f:
    feature_names2 = f.read().split("\n")

model2.feature_names = feature_names2
model2.feature_types = None
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
xgb.plot_importance(model2, max_num_features = 5, ax=ax)
```

So this is saving `feature_names` separately and adding it back in later. For some reason `feature_types` also needs to be initialized, even if the value is `None`.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the feature_names when instantiating the XGBoost Classifier:

```
xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(feature_names=feature_names)
```

Be careful that if you wrap the xgb classifier in a sklearn pipeline that performs any selection on the columns (e.g. VarianceThreshold) the xgb classifier will fail when trying to fit or transform.

Comment: I don't see 'feature_names' being a parameter for xgb.XGBClassifer(). Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If trained with

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    max_depth = 8, 
    learning_rate = 0.25, 
    n_estimators = 50, 
    objective = "binary:logistic",
    n_jobs = 4
)

# x, y are pandas DataFrame
model.fit(train_data_x, train_data_y)
```

you can do `model.get_booster().get_fscore()` to get feature names and feature importance as a python dict

Comment: xgb.plot_importance() works with using XGBClassifier as well :)

Comment: Do you know why do I get different results from plot_importance as feature_importance with xgb models?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the code simpler without the DMatrix. The column names are used as labels:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, plot_importance
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
plot_importance(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the ytick labels using feature_names as a list of strings passed to matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
 xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=5, ax=ax)
 ax.set_yticklabels(feature_names)
 plt.show()
```